# Form Validation that will not allow a user to submit a form without selecting required fields in Vue.js

Tags: html, forms, validation, vue.js

1. When drop downs have been selected, the User will click a Submit button which will send the form to the back-end again. I do not want to allow this button to be pressed if the required fields have not been selected.
   Is there a v-if that will disable the button if fields are not selected?

**HTML**

```
<form id="csvFile" ref="csvFile">
  <div>
    <div class="large-12 medium-12 small-12 cell">
    <input type="file" id="file" ref="file" :change="handleFileUpload()"/>
    <label>File</label>
    <button  @click="getColumnNames()">Upload</button>
    </div>

  <div class="large-12 medium-12 small-12 cell">
    <label>Submit</label>
    <input type="submit" id="columnNames" ref="columnNames"/>
    <button @click="submitFiles()" :="">Files</button>
  </div>
```

**Javascript**

```
    submitFiles() 
    {
      //Form validation that will not allow a user to submit the form by upon the @click event 
      if(!this.$refs.csvFile.checkValidity())
      {
        return null;
      }
      let formData = new FormData();
      formData.append('file', this.file);
      axios.post('http://localhost:8080/api/contacts/upload-csv',
      formData,
      {
      headers: 
        {
          'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data'
        }
      }
      )
      .then(function(response){
        console.log('SUCCESS!!');
        console.log(response);

      })
      .catch(function(response){
        console.log('FAILURE!!');
        console.log(response);

      })
    }




  } 
}
</script>
```

Comment: Instead of posting your entire form here, try to create a small example, maybe with one optional and one required field. That will be a lot easier to think about, and a lot easier to write example code for.

Comment: Sure thing @gnud